Element Loading Issues in Selenium Headless Chrome
I cannot get the page to load when running Selenium WebDriver in headless Chrome, even after introducing a delay and adjusting many ChromeOptions. Here's one of many configurations I tried:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
time.sleep(5)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "some-selector")))
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception caught:", e)

When I omit the headless mode everything works as expected, but no matter what flags and timeouts I use, the page does not load. Could it be a problem with the specific pages I try to access? (I tried many)

Looks like you're using the old headless mode.
Use Chrome's newer headless mode:
options.add_argument("--headless=new")

This makes Chrome's headless mode get the same results as regular Chrome.

Tried both --headless=new and --headless=chrome.
Based on:
[https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/]
Also tried multiple argument combinations. The page does not seem to load, or at least EC.visibility_of_element_located does not seems to respond to it loading.

The traditional --headless, and since version 96, Chrome has a new headless mode that allows users to get the full browser functionality (even run extensions). Between versions 96 to 108 it was --headless=chrome, after version 109 --headless=new.
you can find more details:
https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/
